# Deploying an eclipse based Dynamic Web Project to tomcat7 via Jenkins(remote)?

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins, tomcat7, deploying

I am currently trying to configure a remote VPS (running ubuntu) in a way that it automatically pulls my latest commit from gitlab and deploys it to its tomcat7 instance. 
Short notice: I am not very experienced when it comes to linux, java, tomcat and related stuff.

So far I managed to install tomcat7 and jenkins. Tomcat7 is in `/var/lib/tomcat7` and jenkins is installed in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/jenkins`. Furthermore I added a Job to Jenkins using Source Code Management, that automatically pulls my latest commit. The commit is placed in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/jenkins/workspace/Bigdaxta_build_test`.

The question is: How can I deploy automatically deploy this folder / project to tomcat? I guess I have to add a "post build task" script to do the job. However I cannot find any helpful / comprehensible information on how to do it.

Note: the project pulled by Jenkins hast the following structure:

```
+-- build
¦   +-- classes
¦       +-- bigdaxta
¦           +-- EchoServlet.class
¦           +-- Printer.class
+-- jsch-0.1.53.jar
+-- mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar
+-- pom.xml
+-- README.md
+-- src
¦   +-- bigdaxta
¦       +-- DBConnector.java
¦       +-- EchoServlet.java
¦       +-- Printer.java
+-- target
¦   +-- classes
¦       +-- bigdaxta
¦           +-- DBConnector.class
¦           +-- EchoServlet.class
¦           +-- Printer.class
+-- WebContent
    +-- index.jsp
    +-- META-INF
    ¦   +-- MANIFEST.MF
    +-- test.gif
    +-- WEB-INF
        +-- web.xml
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
Jan